# Android query multiple rows: bind or column index out of range

Tags: android

```
String[] ids = new String[]{"1","2","3","4"};
Cursor emailCur = getContentResolver().query( 
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, 
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", 
                ids, null);
```

I think it should be problem of the included parameter.

I tried to put there

```
String[] ids = new String[]{"(1,2,3,4)"};
// or
String[] ids = new String[]{"('1','2','3','4')"};
```

and tried that with changing `+ " = ?",` to `+ " IN ?",`, didn't worked at all...

I'd like to select all rows with ID in ARRAY, How am I supposed to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that what you are trying to do isn't easily achievable.

Having said that I would tackle the problem by using your original code but changing the where clause to be:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " IN(?,?,?,?)"
```

You will have to add a `?` mark for each id value you wish to specify in the `IN` clause using a for-loop

Comment: Missed your chat message.  Use ids.length to create a string of parameter placeholders.